# Can't upload (deploy) to Google App Engine with app-cfg

Tags: google-app-engine

I can deploy (upload) my files to Google App Engine with using Google App Engine Launcher but I can't do it with appcfg command. I tried with --oauth2 and without --oauth2.

```
$ $APP_ENGINE/appcfg.py --email=my.account@gmail.com --oauth2 update myapp
06:49 PM Application: myapp; version: 20141116
06:49 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:49 PM 
Starting update of app: myapp, version: 20141116
06:49 PM Getting current resource limits.
06:49 PM Scanning files on local disk.
06:49 PM Scanned 500 files.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'myapp').
--- end server output ---


$ $APP_ENGINE/appcfg.py --email=my.account@gmail.com update myapp
06:54 PM Application: myapp; version: 20141116
06:54 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:54 PM 
Starting update of app: myapp, version: 20141116
06:54 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for my.account@gmail.com: 
Invalid username or password.
```

I am sure I input the right password for my gmail (and I disabled application specific password.)  But it says I input wrong password.

I have another account for app engine and I can still deploy for my other account.

I am wondering that I have some problem around credential or specifying the right account while I am using multiple accounts for Google App Engine.

How can I deploy my app to the server?

Thanks,

Comment: Might be corrupted token on your system. use this flag instead of oauth '--noauth_local_webserver' and let me know if it works. It will give you a link, past it into your web browser, get the token and paste it back into the console.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I ran with --noauth_local_webserver but is required to input password like above. I think something in token is corrupted too though.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/ do 'gcloud auth list' to see all your tokens. 'gcloud auth revoke' to clear them all

Comment: Thanks. Ryan. I installed cloud SDK and ran 'gcloud auth list'. The list doesn't have the account I am trying to use.  'gcloud auth revoke' shows HTTPError. Then I tried 'gcloud auth login MY_ACCOUNT'. I have succeeded but still I get the same error when I run 'appcfg.py --email=my.account@gmail.com --oauth2 update myapp'

Comment: Is there an active account set? run " gcloud config set account " followed by the account. Then run a normal appcfg (ie appcfg.py update myapp)

Comment: Yes, I had run "gcloud config set account" and tried to deploy. But still I got the same error in the original post. ("This application does not exist (app_id=u'myapp')."

Comment: What permissions does the account that can't upload have over the project?

Comment: Permission means "Role"? It is "Owner". I am able to upload with this account if I use App Engine Launcher. So, I don't think permission has problem.

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate your keep supporting me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Finally it works. I deleted ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens and authenticate with browser again. Now I can upload my app with command line. I don't know what will happen if I use multiple accounts though.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this trouble today and it set me back 2 hours.
Eventually found this in the comments above

```
rm ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens
```

Went straight back to AppEngineLaucher.app and it ran first time.
Thanks to `[Daisuki Honey]` above for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an application on http://appengine.google.com/. As part of creating the application, you'll choose an application id. After creating the app, edit your app.yaml file and look for the line:

```
application: myapp
```

you the need to replace "myapp" with the application id you chose.

Comment: Actually I already have app ID and succeeded to deploy with App Engine Launcher.

Comment: This was the solution for me